# Treeview taking size of full screen, rather than the frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I ran into this problem, where my Treeview, OwnerTable is not fitting into the frame, rather taking size of whole screen. I have tried every tutorial on the internet, but still am not able to find the solution.

This might be very silly since it is my first project using tkinter.

Please help me out.

```
class employeeClass:
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.geometry("1098x822+342+83")
        self.root.title("Owner")
        self.root.config(bg = "white")
        self.root.focus_force()

        owner_data_Frame = Frame(self.root, bd=2, relief = "solid").place(x=34, y=600, width = 1032, height = 189)
        self.OwnerTable = ttk.Treeview(owner_data_Frame, columns = ("owner_id", "name", "phone_no", "aadhaar_no", "address", "city", "state", "pincode"))

        self.OwnerTable.heading("owner_id", text = "Owner ID")
        self.OwnerTable.heading("name", text = "Name")
        self.OwnerTable.heading("phone_no", text = "Phone No.")
        self.OwnerTable.heading("aadhaar_no", text = "Aadhaar No.")
        self.OwnerTable.heading("address", text = "Address")
        self.OwnerTable.heading("city", text = "City")
        self.OwnerTable.heading("state", text = "State")
        self.OwnerTable.heading("pincode", text = "Pincode")

        self.OwnerTable["show"] = "headings"

        # self.OwnerTable.pack(pady=400)
        self.OwnerTable.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)





if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    obj = employeeClass(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The first step is for you to examine `owner_data_Frame` to see if it’s what you’re assuming it is.

Comment: I did examine the frame but I cannot figure out the error.

Comment: The frame is `None`, meaning the tree widget is going into the root widget instead of the frame.

Comment: how do i resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common error.

```
owner_data_Frame = Frame(self.root, bd=2, relief = "solid").place(x=34, y=600, width = 1032, height = 189)
```

sets the value of **owner_data_Frame** to the value returned by **place(...)**, which always returns **None**.
You must first declare the object, then call its place() method, like this :

```
owner_data_Frame = Frame(self.root, bd=2, relief = "solid")
owner_data_Frame.place(x=34, y=600, width = 1032, height = 189)
```